# Store pdf files in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, file

What data type should I use if I want to store pdf (1mb-20mb) files?
Im using sql server 2008 enterprise edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [FILESTREAM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx). It stores large BLOB data as actual files, which prevents them from affecting the database performance.

Comment: @Jason filestream objects are stored outside the database on a file share. They obey transaction logic, but are not included when you take a database backup

Comment: Filestream data IS included in database backups http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx